# Google Maps with D3.geo.path

Tags: javascript, google-maps, d3.js

I'm trying to follow the example in this videos:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wqPGFs0cqxI

It's about drawing path with D3.js into Google Maps API. The console shows me the error `Uncaught TypeError: Object#<PolylineContext>"  has no method 'setCurrent'`.

The index.html

```
<head>
  <title>App</title>
  <style type="text/css">
      html { height: 100% }
      body { height: 100%; margin: 0; padding: 0 }
      #map-canvas { height: 100%; }
    </style>
  <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp&sensor=false">
    </script>
    <script src="http://d3js.org/d3.v3.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
    <script src="polyline_context.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    var map;
    var polyline;
      function initialize() {
        var mapOptions = {
          center: new google.maps.LatLng(53.567, 9.944),
          zoom: 2,
          mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
        };
        map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map-canvas"),
            mapOptions);
        polyline = new google.maps.Polyline({
          map: map
        });

        d3init();
      }
      var context;
      var width;
      var height;
      var path;
      var graticule;
      var equator;
      var projection;

      function d3init() {
        width = map.getDiv().offsetWidth;
        height = map.getDiv().offsetHeight;

        projection = d3.geo.equirectangular()
          .translate([0, 0])
          .scale(52.29578)
          .precision(2)

        context = new PolylineContext();
        path = d3.geo.path().projection(projection).context(context);
        equator = {type: 'LineString', coordinates: [[-180, 20], [-90, 0], [0, -20], [90, 0], [180, 20]]};

        render();
      }

      function render() {
        polyline.setOptions({
          strokeColor: 'red',
          strokeWeight: 2
        });
        context.setCurrent(polyline.getPath());

        path(equator);
      }

      google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);


    </script>
</head>

<body>

    <div id="map-canvas">
    </div>
</body>
```

The Polyline_context.js

```
'use strict';
function PolylineContext () {
    this.currentPath = null;
    this.currentIndex = 0;
}

PolylineContext.prototype.beginPath = function() {};

PolylineContext.prototype.moveTo = function(x, y) {
    if (this.currentPath) {
        var latLng = new google.maps.LatLng(y, x);
        this.currentPath.setAt(this.currentIndex, latLng);
        this.currentIndex++;
    }
};

PolylineContext.prototype.lineTo = function(x, y) {
    if (this.currentPath) {
        var latLng = new google.maps.LatLng(y, x);
        this.currentPath.setAt(this.currentIndex, latLng);
        this.currentIndex++;
    }
};

PolylineContext.prototype.arc = function(x, y, radius, startAngle, endAngle) {};

PolylineContext.prototype.closePath = function() {};
```

Any ideas of what's wrong in here?

Comment: Isn't this version 3?

Comment: Where did you get this code?  The video says there is a link to the code somewhere, but I couldn't find it, so now I'm using your code from here instead, for my own purposes.   I noticed something funny in it though: the two ends of the curve don't meet, and also the lon/lats specified in the path aren't very accurate in general (confirmed by adding some well-known lon/lats).  BUT I found by binary search that if I change the magic .scale(52.29578) to .scale(57.29578), these problems go away.  So I think that might be a typo in the code?

Comment: Oh!  Googling these two magic numbers, I find that 57.29578 is 180/pi, which certainly makes sense as a scale.  So yeah, the other one must be a typo.

Answer (score 2):

Fairly old question. But just getting started with the same topic. Just in case somebody else stumbles upon this. Just put this inside the `polyline_context.js` file and see it come to live:

```
PolylineContext.prototype.setCurrent = function (path) {
    this.currentPath = path;
};
```

What was shown in the video and what needs to be implemented is not necessarily in sync.

Answer (score 0):

To set the path just use this code instead:

```
context.currentPath = polyline.getPath();
```