# How to draw a hex grid overlay with d3.js on Google Maps

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, d3.js

I'm trying to figure out how to draw an interactive hex grid on top of Google Maps by using d3.js, but I can't seem to find the documentation necessary for this particular implementation.

[Current demo that I'm working with](http://codepen.io/emcniece/pen/aOrNdb)

This is a combination of the [ionic-starter-maps](https://github.com/driftyco/ionic-starter-maps) project with a [d3.js geometry overlay demo](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wqPGFs0cqxI) mixed in ([code for this video is here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18854851/google-maps-with-d3-geo-path)). I plan to utilize some hex grid information from [this article](http://www.redblobgames.com/grids/hexagons/).

The two heavy lifting (I think) functions are here:

```
function d3init() {
  width = map.getDiv().offsetWidth;
  height = map.getDiv().offsetHeight;

  projection = d3.geo.equirectangular()
    .translate([0,0])
    .scale(57.29578)
    .precision(.1)

  context = new PolyLineContext();
  path = d3.geo.path().projection(projection).context(context);
  equator = {type: 'LineString', coordinates: [[-180,20],[-90,0], [0,-20], [90,0], [180,20] ] }

  render();
}

function render() {
  polyline.setOptions({
    strokeColor: 'red',
    strokeWeight: 2
  });
  context.setCurrent(polyline.getPath());
  path(equator);
}
```

Most of the examples I find use the SVG method to draw shapes, but I would like to have *lots* of these hexes so it sounds like canvas might be better suited to the task.

How can I cover the map with a hex grid? What is the best method for adding geometry to the overlay, and should I be looking at `equator = {type: 'LineString',...` as the place to add more coordinates for the hex grid?

Comment: Do  you need to use d3.js to draw the hexagons?  Possible duplicate of [How can I make a Google Maps API v3 hexagon tiled map, preferably coordinate-based?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11761738/how-can-i-make-a-google-maps-api-v3-hexagon-tiled-map-preferably-coordinate-bas)

Comment: Wanted to use d3 for canvas render instead of svg as it's supposed to be better on hardware acceleration. Thanks for the link!!

Comment: 3 years later, and there still doesn't seem to be any decent answer to this question anywhere.